# How to setup a http accessable file server with user managment?

Tags: file, ftp, file-sharing, fileserver, pydio

CompanyX wants a file server setup.  They have several clients they want to share files with, they'd like to give each client a unique username/password and access to their own folder.  The client should then be able to login and upload files and CompanyX could download them.

I want to avoid making either party use an FTP client and I want the files to be accessible via web browser.

What could I use to build something like this? I'm not asking for full directions on how to set this up.

I've found two apps so far, one called Ajaxplorer and another called FileVista they seem similar to what I'm looking for.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use Samba for that.

Simply setup Samba, tell him which directories you want to share, add users for each directory, permissions (write, execute or read). Then each "customer" will access to those folders by using the domainmane.com/folder1 or folder2, etc.. each one of those with different password.

They could simply map the folders using the "MAP network directory" that windows offers.

Or you can use another aproach like setting up folders, use htaccess to protect them and then share the passwords and links for those folders with your "customers"

I don't know those 2 apps that you talked about. but this will help you without using an FTP approach, it may be an unprofessional way to do this, but it works and it's fast to implement.  Other than this you could build a web interface, create users, add different permissions for them or user types, then they can access to the website you want and based on their level of permissions they will see what you want.

Good Luck, and i hope I gave some lights to your problem